# npm failed to install grpc@1.24.2 for Firebase in expo-cli React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm, expo

When I try to install the firebase package for my expo project to do authentication, but it failed to install the package and thrown some unexpected errors.

The command that is used to install the firebase package

```
expo install firebase
```

Errors

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.24.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.24.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Saswat\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-04T02_22_39_477Z-debug.log

npm exited with non-zero code: 1
```

Environment

```
node: 14.15.0
expo-cli: 4.0.13
expo-sdk: 40.0.0
```

please help to resolve my problem

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

1. Remove the lock file and the node_modules directory
2. get the latest version of firebase

   ```
    npm install --save-exact --save firebase@latest
   ```
3. check for vulnerabilities

   ```
    npm audit fix
   ```

then run install

```
     npm install
```

th anyone who is still struggling...

Comment: Here you need to run npm i first and then audit fix. Not audit and npm i, because there's no packages after removing the node_modules folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your node version .You have to use a stable release. To fix  error make a new installation with stable version of node.See the official documentation to get that :https://nodejs.org/fr/download/

Comment: More information on this here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/1183.

The problem is that the library does not appear to ship prebuilt binaries for your Node version, and your machine is failing to build it from source.